# Set Null Property To Empty String With JsonConverter - System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've been trying to deserialize some `null` paramaters with `JsonSerializer` and a custom `JsonConverter` from examples from posts I've seen about the subject, but its not working.

When I debug the `NullToEmptyStringConverter` is seems to be skipping the null parameter `Version` which I have deliberately set to `null` and just returning the `string` values that have a value.  Then when you debug the deserialized object it is `Version = null` still.

```
public class NullToEmptyStringConverter : JsonConverter<string> {

    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) {
        return typeToConvert == typeof(string);
    }

    public override string Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) {
        string value = reader.GetString();

        if(value == null) {
            value = "";
        }
        return value;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializerOptions options) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I have added it to `JsonSerializeOptions` and added the attribute.  Another thing I am confused about is why is the `Read` method being invoked for every parameter even though I have placed it above the `Version` property?

```
public class Application {

    [JsonPropertyName("version")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(NullToEmptyStringConverter))]
    public string Version { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Adding to the `Converter`

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.Converters.Add(new NullToEmptyStringConverter());

var config = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ConfigRoot>(responseData.ToString(), options);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I debug the `NullToEmptyStringConverter` is seems to be skipping the null parameter `Version`...

`JsonConverter<T>` includes a virtual property named `HandleNull`, which is `false` by default. Because of this, `NullToEmptyStringConverter` isn't used for `null` values. Override the getter and set it to return `true`, like this:

```
public override bool HandleNull => true;
```

> ...why is the Read method being invoked for every parameter even though I have placed it above the Version property?

In your example, you have the following line:

> ```
> options.Converters.Add(new NullToEmptyStringConverter());
> ```

This registers `NullToEmptyStringConverter` as a *global* converter. Remove this registration and the converter will run only for the `Version` property, due to the `[JsonConverter]` attribute.